# VB.NET executing stored procedure

Tags: vb.net

I have some problems using a stored procedure in vb.net. I would like to know how to execute a stored procedure, e.g restore backup, by using the stored procedure itself and not its name.

Here is my code:

```
Try

con.ConnectionString = strCon

Dim strCommand as String = "RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
                            FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK'
                            WITH FILE = 1
                            GO"

Dim cm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strCommand, con)

con.Open()

cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When I execute it it says, cannot find stored procedure "RESTORE FILELIST ONLY ,...

So I would like to know if there is a way to execute stored procedure that I write within
visual basic itself as a string. Thanks.

Comment: Why in the world would you want your application restoring a database?

Comment: I am trying to do a lot of more than just restore, i have to restore, then shrink it and do a lot of stuffs, the only problem is to execute a stored procedure that i write inline.

Comment: `GO` is **not** a T-SQL command - just remove it. Also: this has **nothing** to do with a stored procedure - you're using executing an inline SQL statement...

Comment: Have you ever heard of SQL Server Management Studio? You are asking for trouble by doing administrative operations in application data access.

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

try

```
cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

Comment: Isn't that the default?

Comment: @LarsTech I thougth so. But in this case it looks like its trying to interpred text as SP